# $(this).closest('div').find('.notification_wrapper'); How to make the same statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".notifyBtn").click(function(){
   var state = $(this).closest('div').find('.notification_wrapper').css('display');
}
```

I need to find the next closest element  when i click a link. The above jquery code works fine. Can i do the same with javascript alone?

Comment: Yes.. you can.. Show us what you have tried..

Comment: Well for one, that wouldn't even run since theres a syntax error. You're missing a closing parenthesis and semicolon

Comment: @karthikr this is what i tried.

    function findNearest(el, tag) {
        while( el && el.tagName && el.tagName !== tag.toUpperCase()
    {
           el = el.nextSibling();  
        } return el;
     }

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is written in javascript. If you wonder how jQuery apply its method, why don't you dig into its source which are always available as unminified version when you download the package:

### closest()

```
jQuery.fn.closest = function (selectors, context) {
    var cur, i = 0,
        l = this.length,
        ret = [],
        pos = rneedsContext.test(selectors) || typeof selectors !== "string" ? jQuery(selectors, context || this.context) : 0;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        for (cur = this[i]; cur && cur !== context; cur = cur.parentNode) {
            // Always skip document fragments
            if (cur.nodeType < 11 && (pos ? pos.index(cur) > -1 :

            // Don't pass non-elements to Sizzle
            cur.nodeType === 1 && jQuery.find.matchesSelector(cur, selectors))) {

                cur = ret.push(cur);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return this.pushStack(ret.length > 1 ? jQuery.unique(ret) : ret);
};
```

### find()

```
jQuery.fn.find = function (selector) {
    var i, ret = [],
        self = this,
        len = self.length;

    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
        return this.pushStack(jQuery(selector).filter(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (jQuery.contains(self[i], this)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jQuery.find(selector, self[i], ret);
    }

    // Needed because $( selector, context ) becomes $( context ).find( selector )
    ret = this.pushStack(len > 1 ? jQuery.unique(ret) : ret);
    ret.selector = this.selector ? this.selector + " " + selector : selector;
    return ret;
};
```

### css()

```
jQuery.fn.css = function (name, value) {
    return jQuery.access(this, function (elem, name, value) {
        var len, styles, map = {},
            i = 0;

        if (jQuery.isArray(name)) {
            styles = getStyles(elem);
            len = name.length;

            for (; i < len; i++) {
                map[name[i]] = jQuery.css(elem, name[i], false, styles);
            }

            return map;
        }

        return value !== undefined ? jQuery.style(elem, name, value) : jQuery.css(elem, name);
    },
    name, value, arguments.length > 1);
};
```

This is based on jQuery version `1.10.2`